# how do i add the creation of a directory to this cli command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line

I'm traversing a directory, looking for subdirectories, finding certain files, and copying them someplace else... I'm doing this:

```
for i in `ls ./*/filename`; do cp $i ../test2; done
```

This takes all those filenames and moves them into the test2 directory... thing is I also need the source dirname.... i think this can be done with awk but I'm clueless and struggling...

```
for i in `ls ./dirname/filename`; do cp ../test2/dirname/; done
```

I can't copy the entire dirname because I don't need all the files in there...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you are using GNU/Linux maybe the `--parents` option of `cp` is what you are looking for e.g. `cp --parents -t ../test2/ ./*/filename`?

Comment: ... also see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3):

To copy the entire directory path for a particular file or directory to another directory, you have at least two options:

With `cp` from GNU coreutils, use `--parents`:

```
cp --parents ./*/sourcefile /some/path/destdir
```

With `rsync`, use `-R` or `--relative`:

```
rsync -R ./*/sourcefile /some/path/destdir
```

This will place each source file beneath it's source path under the destination directory, so that e.g. `./a/sourcefile` is copied to `/some/path/destdir/a/sourcefile` in the command shown here.

Note that there is no need to loop over any files when doing this.

On a system without GNU `cp` and `rsync`, you could possibly do a loop, but you would not want to loop over the output of `ls`.  Instead

```bash
for pathname in ./*/sourcefile; do
    destdir="/some/path/destdir/$(dirname "$pathname")"
    mkdir -p "$destdir" && cp "$pathname" "$destdir"
done
```

This would loop over all the files you'd like to copy, and for each file, it would make sure that the corresponding destination directory was present and then copy the file there.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dest
`-- src
    |-- a
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- b
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- c
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- d
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    `-- e
        |-- file
        `-- something-else

7 directories, 10 files
```

Either of the above two commands (or the loop) entered here, with the source being `./src/*/file` and the target being `./dest`.

```
$ tree
.
|-- dest
|   `-- src
|       |-- a
|       |   `-- file
|       |-- b
|       |   `-- file
|       |-- c
|       |   `-- file
|       |-- d
|       |   `-- file
|       `-- e
|           `-- file
`-- src
    |-- a
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- b
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- c
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    |-- d
    |   |-- file
    |   `-- something-else
    `-- e
        |-- file
        `-- something-else

13 directories, 15 files
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it with rsync -R (--relative) flag:

```
$ for i in ls ./*/filename; do rsync -avR $i ../test2; done
```

The -R flag syncs the full path given on the command line.

Comment: Did you test that?